# Does chrome respect server priority frame in http/2.0 server push

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, http2, server-push

I am sending priority frame from my server with exclusive dependency flag set. However, I cannot see any priority frame in chrome://net-internals debug log. Also, I can not see any dependency stream update chrome side. Does chrome support/receives priority frame from server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the priority mechanism in HTTP/2 is for the browser to tell the server how it should prioritize things, not the other way around.

That said, your server can simply send things with the right priority, whatever that be for the particular combination of website, browser, and user device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say server can simply send things with the right priority, what do you mean? I am sending priority frame in the context of server push, in order for the browser to change the resource allocation.

Comment: You can just send more frames of a particular CSS file in your HTTP/2 connection than frames of, say, a webfont. Or your server can have some buffering mechanism for files, and provided that it has bytes available for both the CSS and the webfont, prefer to send the bytes of the CSS.